# Cannot cancel a task via CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I am having trouble stopping a Task. Firstly, I just started using Tasks. Previously, I had been using delegate.BeginInvoke() to run things in background, but this time I need to stop background execution, if required. So I switched to Tasks. This is my code:

```
CancellationTokenSource token = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task posting = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoPosting(docs, session), token.Token);
HttpRuntime.Cache[session.ToString() + "_token"] = token;
HttpRuntime.Cache[session.ToString() + "_task"] = posting;
```

This is ASP.NET MVC, so I store long-lasting things in HttpRuntime.Cache. User can cancel operation via this action:

```
public JsonResult StopPosting(string session)
{
    CancellationTokenSource token = (CancellationTokenSource)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(session.ToString() + "_token");
    Task posting = (Task)HttpRuntime.Cache[session.ToString() + "_task"];
    token.Cancel();

    return Json(new { Message = "Stopped!" });
}
```

Now, when this action gets hit for the first time, nothing happens. Then i request cancellation for the second time. Now, token.IsCancellationRequested says "true", so token.Cancel() must have done something. But posting.Status is still "Running". It will stay that way until it completes and then it is "RunToCompletion".

So, I requested cancellation of a Task, but it didt got cancelled.

Maybe I am doing something wrong or I am missing something obvious, but I just cant see/understand why it wont cancel.

Maybe somebody can shed some light?

Regards.

Comment: Not at all. It does heavy duty work with database. I know I should take care what happens there, but i cant get over the first hurdle. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cancelling the token won't immediately result in the task's delegate stopping execution right where it is.  Supporting that (as is done via `Abort` through threads) can cause all sorts of badness, ranging from objects not being cleaned up properly, invariants being violated due to execution stopping part way through an operation that ought to be logically observed to be atomic, etc.

What you need to do is have the actual function being executed look at the CancellationToken and periodically verify that it hasn't been cancelled.  In addition to passing the token to `StartNew` you need to pass it to the `DoPosting` method.  That method then needs to periodically call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` at places in the method where it would be appropriate to stop if cancellation was indeed requested.

See [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/) for further reading.

Comment: OK, I get what you are saying. Will do like that. But one questions pops to my mind, though. What good token is then anyway, I could have DoPosting check for a flag somewhere, and get the same result. Just asking to see what are the benefits of cancellation token?

Comment: @MilosMijatovic There are several factors.  The first is dealing with the synchronization issues.  The `CancellationToken` isn't much more than a wrapper around a bool, but it uses the appropriate memory barriers, etc. to ensure it can be properly observed/mutated from different threads.  Next, it allows the `Task` to differentiate between being canceled and just finishing normally or having an exception be thrown, which can let the continuation act differently for a canceled Task (often useful).  Finally, it allows the `Task` to be marked as cancelled before it has even started.

Comment: Thanks. Good points. I definitely need to to some more reading on the topic.

Comment: Definitely needed token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); inside the loop in the task method that was periodically receiving data . Note can take a little while to action if a lot of data is flowing. Also, if no data flowing then may wait until next data item before aborting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're probably expecting too much of CancellationToken. As regards Tasks, I think the CancellationToken is only used when determining whether to start the task when a slot is available for the task. Once the task is started, the task framework cannot simply abort the delegate call when the CancellationToken is cancelled. In order to fully cancel something like this, the code that is called by the Task framework (DoPosting) must be written to be aware of the CancellationToken and must check the state of that token directly at appropriate points in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your input Michael, also. I was expecting too much.